# Facebook Ads API - How to create NewsFeed ads?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I can successfully create right column ads, but failed to create NewsFeed ads. 
  According to what I know, I should create type 27 creative first, and for this purpose, I need to provide parameter object_id and story_id. The first one is our company's facebook page, and the 2nd one is an unpublished post on that page. 
To create a story, I used the codes below. I think it should be 'promotable_posts'. This is to create an unpublished post in the page so that it can be used in the newsfeed ad.

```
$api.put_connections('id_of_companys_fb_page', 'promotable_posts',
                     {
                         "message" => 'my_message',
                         "name" => "my_name",
                         "link" => "url_of_a_page",
                         "caption" => "my_caption",
                         "description" => "This is a longer description",
                         "picture" => "url_to_a_picture"
                      }
```

Unfortunately it always throws exception "type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, message: Unsupported post request. [HTTP 400] (Koala::Facebook::ClientError)".

If I change 'promotable_posts' to 'feed', then it works, but I cannot use the post id to create the ad, and I noticed that the id starts with 5xxx.. which is different from other manually created posts ids (starting with 1xx..) that worked. I even tried other types, but none works. I didn't find an example to create such post.

Any suggestions, even wild-guess, are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Ads API documentation?

Once you create the page post (via the /feed connection of the page) or have someone create it using the page management interface you create a type 25 or 27 ad using the post ID you retrieve from the API, or from the response of the API call you used to create the post itself.

The `/promotable_posts` endpoint returns the ID of any posts that can be turned into ads, it's a subset of the posts on `/posts`

A sample type 25 and 27 ad creative are included in the 'examples' section of the [Creative Specs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/creative-specs/) documentation

e.g. the type 27 example, modified to use a specific post ID, not the most recent post on the page:

```
curl \
-F "name=sample creative" \ 
-F "type=27" \
-F "object_id=<PAGE ID>" \
-F "story_id= <POST ID>" \
-F "access_token=_____" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_<ACCOUNT ID>/adcreatives"
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm still seeing that error. It says "{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: User did not provide valid story ID -- The provided story ID is not valid. You might have the wrong number, or the story belongs to a different page.","code":1487390}}". <br> Could you provide an example to create the post? I verified my post and page ids and believe that post belongs to the page I used.

Comment: Are you using the long or short form of the story ID? (if you have a story ID of the format XXXXXXX_YYYYYYY only YYYYYYY should be in the 'story_id' parameter of the ad creative) - that's the most likely reason assuming the other things mentioned in the error message aren't true

Comment: I did remove the prefix. When creating post the id returned is 60004615820_3287546762801. The first part is the page id where the post is created. Then I used 3287546762801 as story_id and 60004615820 as the object_id to run the curl command you posted upper.

Comment: (continue.) I noticed that when creating post manually from management interface the id always looks like 1xxxxxxx. One of my suspects is that when creating the post with codes I didn't provide account ID, as you can see from my codes upper. I think I'm posting as a page visitor, not the page owner. That's why I'm not allowed to create ad creative with the post. Could you provide me examples to create such as post?

Comment: So I read your link. It says the token can be retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts with the manage_pages permission. I tried this on API explorer but only get empty array. What does this mean? If that means I don't have manage_pages permission, how come that I can manually create a newsfeed ad? Also, where can I grant my account that permission from web interface?

Comment: If `/me/accounts` returns nothing It means you either didn't grant manage pages permission to the app you're using the access token from, or you don't admin any pages; It sounds like you need to practice with the API in general first, especially the authentication and permissions models, you appear to be trying to jump directly into probably the most complex part of the API (creating and managing ads) without the background knowledge for logging in, making and retrieving posts, etc

Comment: That's true. I'm almost there, but it seems I have to start from the beginning. Thanks!